# Problema en React Native con Hooks y parametros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

estoy haciendo una task-app en react native y tengo un problema al querer pasar 2 parametros para modificar su estado, al presionar el boton, obtiene los parametros correctamente, de echo se ven en consola, pero al momento de que la funcion "handleChangeStatus()" envia los parametros "user_id" y "task_id" al backend, el mismo recibe los parametros "undefined", les dejo el codigo por si ustedes logran encontrar el error, mientras seguiré intentando solucionarlo por mis medios... Espero haberme expresado bien, gracias desde ya.

Codigo en HomeScreen.js:

```
// FUNCION PARA MAEJAR EL CHANGE STATUS Y MANDARLA A BACKEND
  const handleChangeStatus = (user_id, task_id) => {
    console.log("Accion de cambiar estado", user_id, task_id); //Aqui muestra correctamente los parametros
    setChangeStatus(user_id, task_id); //Aqui pasa los parametros undefined
    setRefresh(!refresh);
  };
```

Codigo en el backend request.js:

```
//CAMBIAR STATUS DE TAREAS
export const useChangeStatus = (user_id, task_id) => {
  const [changeStatus, setChangeStatus] = useState([]);
  console.log("change status backend", user_id, task_id)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user_id !== undefined && task_id !== undefined) {
      fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/changeStatus/${user_id}/${task_id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            setChangeStatus("Status update successfully");
          } else {
            throw new Error("Failed to change status");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          setChangeStatus("Failed");
        });
    }
  }, [user_id, task_id]);

  return [changeStatus, setChangeStatus];
};
```

Adjunto la imagen de la consola:
[image: Console]